# Basis Represented By Standard Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that all basis vectors can be represented by the standard basis?

 for example every basis in $R^2$ like $(-2,1),(1,1)$ are linear combination of  $(1,0),(0,1)$

Comment: Well.. all vectors can be represented by the standard basis so I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of a **basis** of a vector space means it is a family $\def\B{\mathcal B}\B$ of vectors such that *any* (single) vector$~v$ can be expressed uniquely as linear combination of the vectors in$~\B$. The coefficients used in that linear combination are called the coordinates of $v$ (with respect to$~\B$). Note that any linear combination gives you one vector, not another basis. So expressing all vectors of a another basis with respect to$~\B$ gives a square matrix of coefficients (a column for each vector if the new basis) which is called a change of basis matrix.

A **standard** basis *only* exists in vector spaces $\mathbf R^n$ (and not for instance in subspaces of it, nor in spaces where vectors are different things to begin with, such as functions). Since here vectors are $n$-tuples of numbers, the standard basis has the property that every vector *is equal* to its collection of coordinates with respect to the basis. In other words expressing a vector in the standard basis requires no work at all, the required coefficients can be taken from the guts of the vector itself.

So to answer the question, in $\mathbf R^2$ (and more generally in $\mathbf R^n$) all vectors can be trivially expressed in the standard basis, and if you've got another basis, then this applies in particular to its vectors (the term "basis vector" does not really have a sense in isolation, as you use it). But "all vectors can be represented by the standard basis" is not true in general, because there is not always such a thing as a standard basis.

Comment: You said standard basis only exist in $R^{n}$ and not in function spaces. Can't we say that the Dirac impulse functions are the equivalent of the standard basis? They are literally zeros everywhere except one place where it is infinite, just like standard basis.

Comment: @JohnDeterious The standard basis actually is not infinite in any place. In very specific kind of spaces of distributions, maybe Dirac distributions form some kind of standard basis in _some_ sense, but not in the sense of linear algebra, as they are not even a Hamel basis of anything useful (finite linear combinations of Diracs are not very interesting things to consider).

Answer (score 1):

Just see this

> $$ (-2,1) = -2(1,0)+(0,1) $$

which is a linear conmination of the standard basis.

Comment: that's mean that every basis vectors can be row raduaced to the standard basis?

Comment: @gbox: Yes that's true. In general you can always find a linear transformation from one basis to another.

Comment: @gbox: Your comment shows you don't quite understand the terminology. There is no such thing as row reducing vectors. One can row reduce a matrix _that is used in a linear system of equations_ to solve the system. A basis is not a matrix, and though I mention a _change of basis_ matrix in my answer, it is not naturally interpreted as a system of equations.

Comment: And the comment by @MhenniBenghorbal is not proper either: a linear transformation goes from one _vector space_ to another, not from one basis to another. Given a pair of bases for the same vector space there are (several) possibilities to introduce linear transformations, but it is not clear which one you would mean, nor which one would be related to (which?) row reduction.